# Vaadin Datefield doesn't recognize weeks in SimpleDateTime formats

Tags: vaadin7, datefield

My core problem is that I want to show the year's week number and the year itself in a Vaadin date-field. For example the user picks the 6th February 2018. The date-field should format its value like "06 2018".

As I understood the documentation of Vaadin 7.7.13, this should easily possible with:

```
public class CalendarWeekField extends DateField {

public CalendarWeekField() {
    super();
    this.setLocale(UI.getCurrent().getLocale());
    this.setDateFormat("ww yyyy");
    this.setShowISOWeekNumbers(true);
}
```

Please recognize the line `this.setDateFormat("ww yyyy");` since it contains the actual "magic".

> The date and time are normally displayed according to the default
>   format for the current locale (see Locale). You can specify a custom
>   format with setDateFormat(). It takes a format string that follows the
>   format of the SimpleDateFormat in Java.

However, following the above example, the output of the DateField is only " 2018".

[image: date format not working]

What do I need to consider to get the year's week numbers displayed?

---

**Consulted documentations:**

- [Java SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [Vaadin Date and Time Input with DateField - Date and Time Format](http://wc.demo.vaadin.com/mcm/out/framework/components/components-datefield.html#components.datefield.popupdatefield.format)
- [Vaadin 7.7.13 API Documentation DateField - setDateFormat(...)](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.7/7.7.13/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html#setDateFormat-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a bug, your code is fine. You can even "fiddle around" with their [live sampler](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/dates/popup-date-field) (hit properties -> date format), the field excepts most date patterns but `ww` (and apparently some timezone-properties). File a bug report maybe?

Maybe you can walk around it by applying a change listener and using `.setText()` yourself? You would not need to extend the DateField in that case (actually there is no need to extend the field in the first place, simply create and set your properties).